# Angular cli assets photo issue - giving 404 not found

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm trying to import the image file from assets folder like this
background: url('../../assets/img/drag-icon.png')

it gives this error and doesn't load the image
`http://localhost:4200/assets/img/drag-icon.png`

I couldn't find those images in dist as well

This is my angularcli.json

> `{   "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json", 
>   "project": {
>       "name": "app-name"   },   "apps": [
>       {
>         "root": "src",
>         "outDir": "dist",
>         "assets": [
>           "[assets]",
>           "favicon.ico"
>         ],
>         "index": "index.html",
>         "main": "main.ts",
>         "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
>         "test": "test.ts",
>         "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
>         "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
>         "prefix": "wf",
>         "styles": [
>           "styles.scss"
>         ],
>         "scripts": [],
>         "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
>         "environments": {
>           "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
>           "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
>         }
>       }   ],   "e2e": {
>       "protractor": {
>         "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
>       }   },   "lint": [
>       {
>         "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json"
>       },
>       {
>         "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
>       },
>       {
>         "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
>       }   ],   "test": {
>       "karma": {
>         "config": "./karma.conf.js"
>       }   },   "defaults": {
>       "styleExt": "scss",
>       "component": {}   } }`

Comment: use `./assets/ ....`

Comment: tried it didn't work

Comment: i couldn't find those images in dist as well

Comment: match your cli and my answer. replace [assets] to assets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your angular cli you need to set you asset dir.    **angular-cli.json**

```
 "apps": [
        {
          "root": "src",
          "outDir": "dist",
          "assets": [
            "assets", // set here your whatever dir  where you store images
            "favicon.ico"
```

**Make Sure your dir in angular cli.**